# podman: chialab/php-dev:8.2-fpm found/not-found on different machines

Tags: debian, container, alpine-linux, podman

I have two VMs running different host Linux OSs and identical `podman-compose.yml` files on the two.

The `podman-compose.yml` file has the snippet:

```
fpm:      
  image: chialab/php-dev:8.2-fpm
  [...]
```

Machine 1 is running an Alpine host and starts up the container and runs the application as intended.  Its podman version is 4.3.1 and that of podman-compose is 1.0.6.

Machine 2 is running Debian 12 but when I run `podman-compose up fpm` it reports:

```
Error: short-name "chialab/php-dev:8.2-fpm" did not resolve to an alias and no unqualified-search registries are defined in "/etc/containers/registries.conf"
```

On this machine, podman is also at version 4.3.1 and `podman-compose` is at version 1.0.3.

I can't find anything in `/etc/containers/registries.conf` on machine 1 that is relevant to the image.

What should I do to make the Debian machine download the image and start the container?

Answer (score 0):

/etc/containers/registries.conf must contain:

```
unqualified-search-registries = ["docker.io"]
```